# How to use jquery to find the element with display=none and return the elements id to a variable?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to to find the element on the page with display set to none and return it's id in a variable. My attempt is below:

```
$(".galleryitem[display='none']").this
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that you need to add `:hidden` psuedo selector. The following will give you the id of selector irrespective of whether it is hidden  or not.

```
var elementId = $(".galleryitem").attr("id");
```

but if you add it will be bit faster-

```
var elementId = $(".galleryitem:hidden").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(".galleryitem:hidden").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery 1.3.2, an element is visible if its browser-reported offsetWidth or offsetHeight is greater than 0. 
What does this change mean? It means that if your element’s CSS display is “none”, or any of its parent/ancestor element’s display is “none”, or if the element’s width is 0 and the element’s height is 0 then an element will be reported as hidden.

Example:

This means the **.galleryitem** element is recognized as hidden only if the parrent has **display: none** style:

```
var elementId = $(".parent .galleryitem:hidden").attr("id");
```

or

```
var elementId = $(".galleryitem:hidden").attr("id");
```

You can choose the example that works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elementId = $(".galleryitem:hidden").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

To find hidden elements you can use the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) psuedo selector.

```
$(".galleryitem:hidden").each(function(){
   //do something with each element.
});
```

Or if you only have one item you can simply do the following:

```
var id = $(".galleryitem:hidden")[0].id
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/AxwAR/1/)**